# vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id not integer

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import time
import random

token = `f`
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


def kick_users(user_id):
    vk.method("messages.removeChatUser",{'chat_id' : 59, 'user_id' : id})


# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():

    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
        if event.to_me:

            # Сообщение от пользователя
            request = event.text

            # Каменная логика ответа
            if request == 'Привет':
                kick_users(event.user_id)
```

По итогу ошибка

> vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id not integer

Если руками вбить ид определенный то всё ок. А мне нужно так, чтобы кикало именно ид того пользователя, который напишет определенное слово/текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, смог сам решить. Всем спасибо)
прописал на id = event.user_id
и потом прописал после сообщений and id != bot_id: